# Setting video start time with the YouTube API - "start" playerVars option used to work, but now does not?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I wrote [this stupid toy](http://jeremyscheff.com/flockas/) using the YouTube API. Basically it just starts multiple copies of a video at different randomized times. That worked great for like a year. But today I noticed that the randomized start times no longer work, it just starts all of the videos at t=0 (tested on multiple browsers/OSes/computers).

Any idea what's wrong? I'm just passing a random number to the [`start`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#start) parameter. Seems simple.

Here's my code. The key part is in the `add` function, where the `start` parameter is set in `playerVars`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flockas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<button id="pause">Pause Flockas</button>
<button id="add">Add One Flocka</button>
<button id="remove">Remove One Flocka</button>
<p>
<div id="flockas"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var flockas = [];

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

function add() {
  var start = Math.random() * 60;

  $("#flockas").append('<div id="flocka' + flockas.length + '" class="flocka"></div>');

  flockas.push(new YT.Player('flocka' + flockas.length, {
    height: '105',
    width: '140',
    videoId: 'yOc-MXGuKgs',
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
      loop: 1,
      playlist: 'yOc-MXGuKgs',
      start: start
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  }));
}

function remove() {
  var divs = $(".flocka");
  $(divs[divs.length - 1]).remove();
  flockas.splice(flockas.length - 1)
}

function pause() {
  var pauseEl = $("#pause");
  if (pauseEl.html() === "Pause Flockas") {
    for (var i = 0; i < flockas.length; i++) {
      flockas[i].pauseVideo();
    }
    pauseEl.html("Play Flockas");
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < flockas.length; i++) {
      flockas[i].playVideo();
    }
    pauseEl.html("Pause Flockas");
  }
}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    add();
  }
}

$("#add").click(add);
$("#remove").click(remove);
$("#pause").click(pause);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Like I said above, this worked fine when I originally made it, and I only very recently noticed that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start parameter still works. The problem is, that you compute a wrong value for it: wrong type.
Maybe it has been changed: 
Supplying a valid INTEGER value works. (If fractions are allowed, then not all are valid.)

For example, if you want a value between 0 and 200 then use:

```
  var maxVal = 200;
  var startVal = Math.ceil((Math.random() * maxVal));
```