# youtube iframe api to show multiple videos

Tags: youtube-api

i have a partial view with razor engine looking something like this

```
@model Tool.MVC.Areas.Widget.Models.VideoWidgetModel
@{
var baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"];
var youTubeUrl=Model.ModalExitUrl;
var videoId="video_widget_"+Model.UniqueVideoId;
}
<div class="@videoId">
<div id="@videoId"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@baseUrl/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var youTubeUrlRegex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
  var ytUrl = '@youTubeUrl';
 var ytUrlId = (ytUrl.match(youTubeUrlRegex)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;


//Load player api asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
console.log(tag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

    player = new YT.Player('@videoId', {
      height: '290',
      width: '220',
      videoId: ytUrlId,
      events: {

      }
    });
}
</script>
</div>
```

VideoId is generating a Guid in order to have distinct id for a div each time i have a partial on my page.
but when i render the page ,in my page i have two partials each with one video,so two times will load this page ,but only the last is showing the video in a Youtube player,the other just says that YT.player is undefined,so i presume is not loading the IframeApi.
how can i load many times this Youtube player and its Api in order to show as many videos as i like.

I really appreciate an answer,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The api script needs to be loaded only once. But each player needs a unique reference.
Here is a link to code of a working example:
[Setting video start time with the YouTube API - "start" playerVars option used to work, but now does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821157/setting-video-start-time-with-the-youtube-api-start-playervars-option-used-t)
However the example code is not model based.

Maybe something like:

```
    var players = Array(); // Should be a global var for reference to all the players

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        var player; // not usable for reference
        player = new YT.Player('@videoId', {
                     height: '290',
                     width: '220',
                     videoId: ytUrlId,
                     events: {

                             }
                  });
        players.push(player); // Saving player reference in a global var
    }
```

Comment: yes but in this case i do not know at the beginning how many players i will use,so it's dinamically

Comment: @kingjulian You can create the first player in onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(). And then allow the creation of others only if the first one has been created. The thing is, that you must wait for the call of onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(), before creating players.

Comment: @kingjulian Did you check the link a mentioned at the bottom of my answer ? That example starts with creating 5 players, but you can change that to any other value, like 1 for example. It also shows a button "Add One Flocka" to create subsequent players.

Comment: yes but you know that u want 5 times,with the for loop,in my case i get each time this partial with a  videoId from model and that's it.somehow i have to create a dinamic array based on this id.that's why an ilustration of you ideea on this example would help .

Comment: @kingjulian The thing is I don't know about "partial view with razor engine" that you use. You want multiple players but you assign all of them to the same var: player. It should NOT be the same single var every time. Either an array element or a different var name.

Comment: your ideea is good, create separate players, but i do not know their count,so how can i do that?

Comment: @kingjulian Changed my answer.